# Number of duplicates of a pair of columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this format

```
first_name last_name
```

and I want to show the pairs of "first_name" and "last_name" that appear exactly twice at the database. I've used this

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*)
from employees
having count(*)=2;
```

which is wrong and I am not sure what it's doing. It's my first sql approach so please be patient :) *Working with mysql workbench

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by`:

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*)
from employees
group by first_name, last_name
having count(*)=2;
```

Comment: What does group by actually do?

Comment: @BillyGrande it applies all used aggregation functions (in this case `count`) on the results having the same value(s) you are grouping by.

Answer (score 2):

```
         select first_name, last_name, count(*)
        from employees
        group by first_name, last_name
         having count(*)=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by and then using having clause for this..

Query is:

select first_name, last_name, count(*) from employees  group by first_name, last_name having count(*)=2;